# hibernate - HQL joins on many clauses

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, left-join

I've been reading Hibernate documentation, but I haven't found anything that would explain how to do the following.

I have the following SQL code that I'm trying to convert to HQL:

```
SELECT {msg.*}, {cmd.*} 
FROM Schema.Messages AS msg 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.send_commands AS cmd 
    ON cmd.message_key = msg.unique_key 
    AND ( lower(cmd.status) IN (lower('failed') ) ) 
WHERE msg.sequence_received < 10";
```

The mainissue I'm having is that I'm unable to have two clauses on a LEFT OUTER JOIN. HQL allows me to have 
     `ON cmd.message_key = msg.unique_key`
, but how do I add the 
`AND clause 2?`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add extra join conditions using `with` keyword, something like this (depends on your mapping):

```
SELECT m, c 
FROM Message m LEFT JOIN m.commands c WITH (lower(c.status) = 'failed')
WHERE m.sequenceReceived < 10
```

**See also:**

- [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Comment: thanks. this worked.  will it also work as with two arguments as in:
`WITH (lower(c.status) = 'failed') AND (c.dateReceived < someDate )` ?