# Syntax Error for HQL JOIN Statment

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, hql

I'm trying to create a HQL query to join a result of a select with another table.  What I have currently is

`SELECT e FROM Experience e JOIN (SELECT f FROM Follow f WHERE f.username = :username AND f.contentType = :contentType) AS A ON (e.experienceId = A.contentId);`

Its SQL equivalent that currently works is

`SELECT t_experiences.* FROM t_experiences JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_follows WHERE t_follows.username = :username AND t_follows.content_type = :contentType) AS A ON (t_experiences.experience_id = A.content_id);`

Where `t_experiences.experience_id` is equivalent to `Experience.experienceId`, etc.  The current error in the HQL is on the first `(` with `unexpected token: (` error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don.t you try this:

```
SELECT e.experienceId FROM Experience e, Follow f WHERE f.username = :username AND f.contentType = :contentType AND (e.experienceId = f.contentId);
```

I think this should work for you.

`Note: Replace e.experienceId by parameters which you want.`

Comment: Does `e.*` work to get all columns?  I don't know the equivalent in HQL.

Comment: or anyone else if you know.

Comment: I have not tried but from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345052/hibernate-hql-joins-on-many-clauses) post it seems that it should work..
`SELECT e FROM Experience e, Follow f WHERE f.username = :username AND f.contentType = :contentType AND (e.experienceId = f.contentId);`

Please try this but I am not sure. And it work for you please tell me.